# jQuery each loop give only first result

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to generate an array to be submitted to an ajax call via jQuery. Here is my HTML and JavaScript:

```js
//Following is the JavaScript I use to generate the variables from checked checkboxes

jQuery(document).on("click", ".refno", function() {
  var ref = jQuery(this).data("ref");
  var refindex = jQuery(this).data("refindex");

  var i = 0;
  var tutelists = [];
  var tutearray = {};
  jQuery('.datarefindex_' + refindex).each(function() {
var subjid = jQuery(this).data("subjid");
i++;

tutearray["id"] = subjid;
tutearray["issuedtutes"] = jQuery("input[name=tuteset_" + refindex + "_" + subjid + "]:checked").map(function() {
  return this.value;
}).get();

  });
  tutelists.push(tutearray);
  var tutelists = JSON.stringify(tutelists);

  jQuery("#responsecontainer").html(tutelists);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="refno" data-refindex="1" data-ref="1105898">1105898</a>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>Title 1</div>
    <ul class="datarefindex_1" data-subjid="opt471821">
      <li>
        <label class="tutebtn" for="1_opt471821_1">
                            <input name="tuteset_1_opt471821" data-mainrefindex="1" type="checkbox" id="1_opt471821_1" data-subj="opt471821" value="1"> 1</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label class="tutebtn" for="1_opt471821_2">
                            <input name="tuteset_1_opt471821" data-mainrefindex="1" type="checkbox" id="1_opt471821_2" data-subj="opt471821" value="2"> 2</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Title 2</div>
    <ul class="datarefindex_1" data-subjid="opt1215754">
      <li>
        <label class="tutebtn" for="1_opt1215754_1">
                            <input name="tuteset_1_opt1215754" data-mainrefindex="1" type="checkbox" id="1_opt1215754_1" data-subj="opt1215754" value="1"> 1</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label class="tutebtn" for="1_opt1215754_2">
                            <input name="tuteset_1_opt1215754" data-mainrefindex="1" type="checkbox" id="1_opt1215754_2" data-subj="opt1215754" value="2"> 2</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Title 3</div>
    <ul class="datarefindex_1" data-subjid="opt3062581">
      <li>
        <label class="tutebtn" for="1_opt3062581_1">
                            <input name="tuteset_1_opt3062581" data-mainrefindex="1" type="checkbox" id="1_opt3062581_1" data-subj="opt3062581" value="1"> 1</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label class="tutebtn" for="1_opt3062581_2">
                            <input name="tuteset_1_opt3062581" data-mainrefindex="1" type="checkbox" id="1_opt3062581_2" data-subj="opt3062581" value="2"> 2</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="responsecontainer"></div

>
```

The result I receive is as follows (I have checked the first 3 boxes in each list);

```
{"id":"opt3062581","issuedtutes1":["1","2","3"],
"issuedtutes2":["1","2","3"],
"issuedtutes3":["1","2","3"]}
```

However the desired result is as follows;

```
{"id":"opt471821","issuedtutes":["1","2","3"]},
{"id":"opt1215754","issuedtutes":["1","2","3"]},
{"id":"opt3062581","issuedtutes":["1","2","3"]}
```

Couldn't figure out what am I missing. When i remove the `id` part from the function, this returns `{"id":"opt3062581","issuedtutes":["1","2","3"]}` which is the data from the last list. Please help.

Number of tute lists is dynamic and not fixed.

Comment: create `tutelists = {}` inside the loop, then push it to an array that you should create out of loop

Comment: @CalvinNunes No luck! `[{"id":"opt3062581","issuedtutes1":["1","2","3"],"issuedtutes2":["1","2","3"],"issuedtutes3":["1","2","3"]}]` I did this **after** i tried the same suggestion given in both answers below

Comment: so please, [edit] your question and add a [mcve] that works, because right now, your code in the snippet don't do anything and many elements that you use jQuery(...) doesn't exist...

Comment: @CalvinNunes please check now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expected output looks like a list of objects, so `tutelists` should be a list not an object.

```js
jQuery(document).on("click", ".refno", function() {
  var ref = jQuery(this).data("ref");
  var refindex = jQuery(this).data("refindex");

  var i = 0;
  var tutelists = [];
  jQuery('.datarefindex_' + refindex).each(function() {
var subjid = jQuery(this).data("subjid");
i++;
  var tutearray = {};

tutearray["id"] = subjid;
tutearray["issuedtutes"] = jQuery("input[name=tuteset_" + refindex + "_" + subjid + "]:checked").map(function() {
  return this.value;
}).get();
  tutelists.push(tutearray);

  });
  var tutelists = JSON.stringify(tutelists);

  jQuery("#responsecontainer").html(tutelists);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="refno" data-refindex="1" data-ref="1105898">1105898</a>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>Title 1</div>
    <ul class="datarefindex_1" data-subjid="opt471821">
      <li>
        <label class="tutebtn" for="1_opt471821_1">
                            <input name="tuteset_1_opt471821" data-mainrefindex="1" type="checkbox" id="1_opt471821_1" data-subj="opt471821" value="1"> 1</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label class="tutebtn" for="1_opt471821_2">
                            <input name="tuteset_1_opt471821" data-mainrefindex="1" type="checkbox" id="1_opt471821_2" data-subj="opt471821" value="2"> 2</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Title 2</div>
    <ul class="datarefindex_1" data-subjid="opt1215754">
      <li>
        <label class="tutebtn" for="1_opt1215754_1">
                            <input name="tuteset_1_opt1215754" data-mainrefindex="1" type="checkbox" id="1_opt1215754_1" data-subj="opt1215754" value="1"> 1</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label class="tutebtn" for="1_opt1215754_2">
                            <input name="tuteset_1_opt1215754" data-mainrefindex="1" type="checkbox" id="1_opt1215754_2" data-subj="opt1215754" value="2"> 2</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Title 3</div>
    <ul class="datarefindex_1" data-subjid="opt3062581">
      <li>
        <label class="tutebtn" for="1_opt3062581_1">
                            <input name="tuteset_1_opt3062581" data-mainrefindex="1" type="checkbox" id="1_opt3062581_1" data-subj="opt3062581" value="1"> 1</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label class="tutebtn" for="1_opt3062581_2">
                            <input name="tuteset_1_opt3062581" data-mainrefindex="1" type="checkbox" id="1_opt3062581_2" data-subj="opt3062581" value="2"> 2</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="responsecontainer"></div

>
```

Comment: I don't think the `+i` in temp["issuedtutes"+i] is the desired result.

Comment: Thank. But no luck! Still what i get is the last list ID and the checked items array, **not** all lists. ;(

Comment: @Sid see my updated answer, the code needs to be in the each loop

Answer (score 1):

Your `id` value will be replaced with new newer one. Please try to use `push()` method of array to make it workable.

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ".refno", function () {
    var ref = jQuery(this).data("ref");
    var refindex = jQuery(this).data("refindex");

    var i = 0;
    var tutelists =[];
    tutelistElement = {};
    jQuery('.datarefindex_'+ refindex ).each(function(){
        var subjid = jQuery(this).data("subjid");
        i++;

        tutelistElement["id"] = subjid;
        tutelistElement["issuedtutes"+i] = jQuery("input[name=tuteset_"+refindex+"_"+subjid+"]:checked").map(function () { return this.value; }).get();

    });
    tutelists.push(tutelistElement);
    var tutelists = JSON.stringify(tutelists);

    jQuery("#responsecontainer").html(tutelists);

});
```

Comment: Thank. But no luck! Still what i get is the last list ID and the checked items array, **not** all lists. :( Also i do not need the `+i` from my array

Comment: Would you please update your code which will display the array result

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you meant. The result I get is there :O When the change is made I get `[{"id":"opt3062581","issuedtutes":["1","2","3"]}]` which is coming from the last list